# How to force relative source map URL to follow redirect

Tags: javascript, html, unpkg

I have a package [parse-ingredient](https://npmjs.com/package/parse-ingredient), which has a demo page [here](https://jakeboone02.github.io/parse-ingredient/). The demo page depends on another of my packages called [numeric-quantity](https://npmjs.com/package/numeric-quantity). The demo page just fetches the latest UMD versions of each package from [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/) like this:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/numeric-quantity"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/parse-ingredient"></script>
```

Each package has a source map identified as a relative URL, like this (abbreviated version of `numeric-quantity.umd.js`):

```js
(function(n,d){typeof exports=="object"&&typeof module!="undefined"? // ...etc, etc, etc
//# sourceMappingURL=numeric-quantity.umd.js.map
```

When the demo page is loaded in Chrome, this appears in the console:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for `https://unpkg.com/numeric-quantity.umd.js.map`: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Similar errors appear in other browsers. I believe this is because the browser thinks that since the original requested URL is `https://unpkg.com/numeric-quantity`, then the `sourceMappingURL` should be relative to *that* location, not the redirect URL that UNPKG actually resolves to (`https://unpkg.com/browse/numeric-quantity@1.0.4/dist/numeric-quantity.umd.js`).

Is this something I can fix with configuration? If not, is it a problem UNPKG can fix? And if not that, then is this something the browsers are actually doing wrong?

[Relevant UNPKG GitHub issue](https://github.com/mjackson/unpkg/issues/327)

Comment: Follow-up question: do browsers give precedence to the `SourceMap` HTTP header over the `sourceMappingURL` comment directive when both are present in a response?

Comment: maybe a chromium bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1403799

Comment: I filed a bug for Firefox as well: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1823809